# Battery level on Asus eee pad Transformer with dock

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I'm wondering if anybody knows how the battery level is measured on the Transformer when the dock is connected.

I fully charged the other day, and after few hours of use the battery level was still 100%, so my first thought is that first uses the dock battery until this one is empty and the continues with the tablet's battery.

Can anyone confirm/deny my guess about the battery level measurement on this tablet?

Also, does it work the same when you charge the tablet though the dock, that is, starts charging the dock and when is fully charged continues with the tablet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eee Pad Transformer will use the battery of the dock to both power and charge the tablet so long as it is connected. You can see this when docked and on battery because the tablet shows its battery as "charging". This gets the most use out of the tablet because when you undock it, it is most likely to have more charge than the dock.

When docked and on the charger, I am fairly sure that both charge at the same time. However, I haven't checked as my TF is docked most of the time.

Incidentally, if the dock's battery goes flat, it gets its power from the tablet (without trying to recharge its own battery).